# How to highlight duplicate text from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, duplicates

I have two sheets: one contains master data with all the personal information, the other new data on a daily basis.

I would like to highlight the text on the new sheet from the old one basis on duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

In excel the process can be done by using conditional formatting -> 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' ->  =First cell=Sheet(X)!First cell

In google sheets add the command Indirect

Ex1: If interested in entire table on both sheets then formula would be =A1=Indirect(SheetMaster!A1)
Ex2: If interested in one column in each sheet: =D2=Indirect(SheetMaster!D2)

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you explain little bit more. Basically I am highlighting 4 columns from old sheet to new sheet. It would be very helpful if you show me example.